# Using logback, how to compress files older than maxHistory?

Tags: playframework, logback, gzip

I'm using Play Framework 2.3.7 with Logback.

I have the following appender:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/${LOG_FILE}</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/${LOG_FILE}.${ROLLING_PATTERN}.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>${MAX_DAYS_HISTORY}</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush> 
        <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Is there any way to compress to gz only files older than ${MAX_DAYS_HISTORY} ?

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Having .gz on the rolling fileNamePattern should already do this AFAIK? Is that not working?

Comment: The .gz extension on the fileNamePattern compresses the file as soon as the rolling occurs. What I need is to compress files older than the maxHistory attribute. Ex.: If roll the files per day and maxHistory is 90 then only files > 90 days old will get compressed.